# Set primary key in very large database

Tags: sql-server

I have a very large table (around 13 million rows) and I want to set the primary key for the tables. The problem is that given the large size of the database my computer crashes when I try to set the primary key for a table.

I suppose that SQL Server tries to set this key in every row it finds, so the memory consumption reaches the limit of my computer (6gb of memory). Is there any effective and alternative way to set the primary key without having these issues?

Comment: What is the type of the column: numerical or string?

Comment: Are you adding a new column as the primary key or are you using an existing column as the PK?  If you are using an existing, how do you know its unique?

Comment: I'm assuming you are adding some sort of auto numbering key. Do you care about the ordering of rows? i.e. which rows is assigned which number or does that not matter?

Comment: Adding the primary key will actually also add a clustering key, and if no clustering key exists on that table now, doing so will **totally** change your table structure. It's **not** a trivial operation! All data pages for all rows will be picked up, physically shuffled around on your disk and placed into sequence according to the clustering key .... this is a **massive** operation!

Comment: So if you really want to add **just** the primary key, you could use `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED` - however, in that case, you **loose** all the benefits of having a clustering index (vs. having a heap table....)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the type of column is int

Answer (score 7):

Here are a couple of options that might work:

1. Create a new table with the same columns and a primary key, and select into it from the other table.
2. Create a change script and and disable the execution timeout in SSMS

Here's a change script to point you in the right direction:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tableName PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (columnName)
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 75, ONLINE = ON, PAD_INDEX = ON)
```

Comment: +1: I'd go for option 1 if disk space is not an issue, which it shouldn't be with such a small table ;)

Comment: +1 for option 1. Either way, the table will have to be recreated. Option 1 can be minimally logged (pending you meet the requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a new table with the appropriate primary key. Script out any relationships besides the basic table structure on the intial table. Set the datbase into single user mode (so no one can change the records while you are in the process of transferring them) after making sure you have a current backup.

Then insert records from teh old table in bathces of say 10000 at a time. It will take longer than one set-based insert but will be far less likely to time out. You may have to experiement to find the optimum batch size. After you are done, drop the old table, rename the new table and set up any pk/fk relationships again. Then go out of single user mode.

This is a task that should only be done on production during non-busy hours and as a database maintenance task, no one else should be allowed to access the database while it occurs.

Note you may not have unique information on the natural key of the table. IN this case you could have an issue if you are using that as the pk and may need to move some records to an exception table to fix. Even if you are using a surogate key as the new PK, I highly recommend a unique index on the natural key of the table if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons I have seen for this is the amount of memory that SQL Server can allocate is very much larger then what your machine is willing to give and so you end up crashing it.  Try to change the memory allocated to SQL Server to a smaller memory foot print and see if that is the cause.  SQL Server should be able to handle that many records, but if it tries to load them all into memory at the same time to do the job that could cause your issue.